# how to make field unique for current user django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've got Skill model like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    percentage = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])
    expirience = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(80)])
```

And now I want to make field "title" unique for current user, so User1 couldn't create 2 skills with same titles, but User1 and User2 both could create skill with same titles.

I guess there must be some simple solutions without such validation in skill_new() view, but couldn't find any.

Comment: [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use model Meta

```
class Skill(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ("user", "title")
```